# ASP.net & C# & Could not load type

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, visual-studio-2013, namespaces

I am a noob with visual studio. I recently setup this to begin testing some ASP files to grab data from a sql server. Using IIS. After many trial and errors, I got my first sql query working and storing it into a gridview (which is cool). However, when I began to make links between pages, to make new queries on different pages, I broke it.

I suspect a rookie mistake with the c# code since I am not proficient or with visual studio since I am so unfamiliar with how it works.

I've done a decent amount of searching on why this doesn't work and struck out with (1) the output bin location. (2) rebuilding the file (3) restarting VS (4) renaming namespace and class.

[image: Debug error]

My index.aspx page works, and clicking on the link to my guinea.aspx just loads a previous cached page (hitting refresh generates the error message). Above is line 1 of my guinea and below is the beginning set of code for the aspx.cs. Below this code is the sql query info which does not appear related.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

namespace Guinea
{
    public partial class Pig : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, after a lot of trial and error. Basic mistakes any new user might do with little experience using visual studio.

(1) In the Solution explorer, my other links were not part of my solution/website. They needed to be added to it by right-click on assembly and add existing item.
(2) Since I did save as to make new pages and then slightly changed its content, on the designer files aspx.designer.cs.none of the references/names matched the new pages. They referenced the old file names. Fixed by renaming all variables as necessary.

Re-build and works fine.